# Container-managed transaction in JAX-WS, weblogic

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm trying to use Container-Managed Transactions inside webservice, but transaction isn't created. I have something like that:

```
@WebService(...)
@Stateless
@TransactionManagment(TransactionManagmentType.CONTAINER)
public class ExampleService {

  // EntityManager and other fields

  @TransactionAttribure(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
  public void test(String s){
     // persist something with EntityManager
  }
}
```

When I call this method, I get javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: The method public abstract void javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist(java.lang.Object) must be called in the context of a transaction.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the persistence unit in persistence.xml set to transaction-type="JTA"?

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall 'TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED' means that method should be only called when transaction is already in progress for current thread (in other words 'called in context of transaction'). It's not clear who if anybody starts transaction in your case. If nobody then the exception you're getting makes perfect sense.

Now I'm not sure how or is it even currently possible to propagate transaction across Web services call. I don't think this is particularly good idea to do so even if possible.

Perhaps you what you need TransactionAttributeType.REQURES_NEW in your case so Container would start the transaction before passing control to your annotated method?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however according to http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRED new transaction must be started.  Exactly, I'd like to get new transaction when method is called

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like: @Transactional(value=Transactional.TransactionFlowType.MANDATORY,
           version=com.sun.xml.ws.api.tx.at.Transactional.Version.WSAT10)

Comment: See here: http://metro.java.net/guide/Using_Web_Services_Atomic_Transactions.html

Comment: are you talking about 2p commit transaction? I don't need it in fact

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with 2pc or 1pc - the annotations should be the same in either case

Comment: I tried it, but it seems required some changes on client code, that isn't allowed